# Remove a css property from a css class and create another css class

Tags: css, sass

I have a css class for a button

```
.uploadImage-button {
  @include myTheme.theme-aware('background-color', 'formImageUploadButtonColor-bg');
  min-width: 10rem;
  height: 3.125rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

I need the same css class properties of uploadImage-button except  margin-right: 3rem; not included in it.
is there a way to achieve this